# Mapping and writing a custom class to csv

Tags: c#, csv, export-to-csv, csvhelper

I'm trying to output some data to a CSV file using CsvHelper. One row for each instance of `CSVExport` below. Each row could have varying number of columns as the length on `Stores` could be different. The mapping works for the first three properties (CurrencyCode, StoreCode, OutletTradingName) but I'm having issues with the `List<Stores> Stores`.

I currently get the following error message with the below code:

```
{"Converting IEnumerable types is not supported for a single field. If you want to do this, create your own ITypeConverter and register it in the TypeConverterFactory by calling AddConverter."}
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

C# code to write to csv file:

```
var memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
var streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(memoryStream);
using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter))
{
    csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CSVExportMap>();
    csvWriter.WriteRecords(csvExport);
    streamWriter.Flush();
}
```

mapping:

```
public sealed class CSVExportMap : CsvClassMap<CSVExport>
{
    public CSVExportMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.CurrencyCode).Name("Outlet Currency").Default("Not available.");
        Map(m => m.StoreCode).Name("Store No.").Default("Not available.");
        Map(m => m.OutletTradingName).Name("Outlet Trading  Name").Default("Not available.");

        // if I comment this line out, I get no error but no list of stores
        Map(m => m.Stores).ConvertUsing( row => new List<Stores> { row.GetRecord<Stores>() } );
    }
}
```

Class I'm trying to output to CSV file:

```
public class CSVExport
{
    public string StoreCode { get; set; }
    public string OutletTradingName { get; set; }
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
    public List<Stores> Stores { get; set; }
}

public class Stores
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string StoreCode { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have latest version of [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/). (currently v7.1.1) I tried your code and replaced this line:

```
Map(m => m.Stores).ConvertUsing( row => new List<Stores> { row.GetRecord<Stores>() } );
```

with this:

```
Map(m => m.Stores).ConvertUsing(row =>
{
    var list = new List<Store>();
    list.Add(row.GetField<Store>(2));
    return list;
});
```

Or shorter (One Liner):

```
Map(m => m.Stores).ConvertUsing(row => new List<Store> {row.GetField<Store>(2)});
```

and program worked without problem. Index in `GetField<Store>(2)` is zero-based and your `Store` class have 3 members. I just rename your `Stores` class to `Store` (Only for naming convention! It was confusing with Stores list property! Sorry)

I used this tip:
[Writing a collection that contains collections](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/389)